# Part is positioned To WorldOrigin instead of intended CFrame

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

I'm trying to create a plug system somewhat like Half Life 2 Ep 2's. What this script does is whenever a proximity prompt is triggered on a plug, it's supposed to be rotated and positioned to the players arm and welded.

Whenever you activate the proximity prompt, it's rotated and welded fine, but it is positioned at the world origin (0, 0, 0). I've tried to change how it is positioned multiple times. I think it is only the line that is positioning the part that is causing the problem, but im not 100% sure. I don't get any errors. Also, the primary parts have other parts welded to it, could that be causing an issue?

```lua
for _, plug in pairs(collectionservice:GetTagged('Plug')) do
    plug.PrimaryPart.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function(plr)
        local plugval = plr.Character:WaitForChild('HoldingPlug', 1)
        plugval.Value = plug
        plug.PrimaryPart.Anchored = false
        plr.Character:WaitForChild('Humanoid'):UnequipTools()
        game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').Events.EquipPlug:FireClient(plr)
        local arm = plr.Character:FindFirstChild('Right Arm')
        plug.PrimaryPart.CFrame = CFrame.new(arm.CFrame.Position.X,arm.CFrame.Position.Y,arm.CFrame.Position.Z)
        local rx,ry,rz = plr.Character:FindFirstChild('Right Arm').CFrame:ToOrientation()
        plug.PrimaryPart.CFrame = CFrame.Angles(math.rad(rx),math.rad(ry),math.rad(90))
        local weld = Instance.new('WeldConstraint')
        weld.Parent =  plug.PrimaryPart
        weld.Name = 'PlayerWeld'
        weld.Part0 = arm
        weld.Part1 = plug.PrimaryPart
        plug.PrimaryPart.CanCollide = false
    end)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

CFrame.Angles creates a new CFrame, what you want is to do add them (multiplying replaces adding for CFrames idk why)
So:

```
plug.PrimaryPart.CFrame = plug.PrimaryPart.CFrame * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(rx),math.rad(ry),math.rad(90))
```